# How do I prove something is Turing recognizable?

Tags: turing-machines

I need to prove that natural numbers are Turing recognizable. How do I start? 
I understand the basic definition of Turing recognizable and Turing decidable, but am having a hard time applying it to proofs

Comment: `How do I start?` Probably not on StackOverflow.

Comment: Describe an algorithm that recognizes them.

Comment: Are there any other sites that can help me with what I need?